# Forcing divs next to themselves

Tags: html, css, fiddle

I have, again, met a complication. And again, this is probably one a novice could bypass, but I can't.

Basically, what I'm trying to do:

- Get the `green` div under the `red` div
- Have the bottommost divs go up with it
- Have a border of `4px` be between every div

An example based off of [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xr5eLxds/1/) would be nice.

Comment: I suggest using a jquery / css library such as masonry.js https://masonry.desandro.com/ It's a neat & easy way to achieve what you're trying to do (+ it's responsive)

Comment: What you want is, if you dont want it hardcoded, quite difficult. Most solutions require a JS plugin

Comment: @TimGerhard Yeah, that's what I'm looking for... After putting it into the HTML file, how do I continue?

Comment: Just scroll down on the page I sent you. It's well docmented

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the div of green just add margin-top as :

`margin-top:-84px`

as i have experimented it on your fiddle and it's working

Comment: This was everything the code needed... Guess complicated solutions are too much sometimes... Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There object properties with which you can define the position from an object. 
For example: "`absolute`" and "`relative`" https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

```css
.red  {
            height: 200px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: red;
            border: solid white 4px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .green {
            height: 60px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            border: solid white 4px;
            margin-top: 102px;
        }
        .verypurple {
            height: 60px;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: darkviolet;
            border: solid white 4px;
        }
        .yellow{
            height: 60px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: solid white 4px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 154px;
        }
        .purple{
            height: 130px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: purple;
            border: solid white 4px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 154px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .blue{
            height: 130px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: blue;
            border: solid white 4px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 154px;
            margin-top: 174px;
        }
        .darkbrownish{
            height: 60px;
            width: 70px;
            background-color: gray;
            border: solid white 4px;
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 204px;
            margin-top: 378px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="yellow">
    yellow
</div>
<div class="purple">
    purple
</div>
<div class="blue">
    blue
</div>
<div class="darkbrownish">
    dark<br>
    brownish
</div>
<div class="red">
    red
</div>
<div class="green">
    green
</div>
<div class="verypurple">
    very purple
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Masonry for your layout.

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 4px;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[See here](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/) for more details.